# SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found. struts.xml

Tags: struts2, xml-configuration

I am developing a  Struts+Hibernate web application. I  confronted with the following error with `struts.xml`:

> Unable to load configuration. - file:/F:/BidNext/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:9:8**
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/F:/BidNext/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml; >lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 8; Document is invalid: no grammar found.

**Here is my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="auction" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="signupaction" class="struts.action.SignUpAction">
            <result name="SUCCESS">/Home.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: The file is outdated.

Comment: @RomanC Roman, can you please elaborate.What exactly is the problem or what is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is when the application starts. The configuration file `struts.xml` which should be on classpath had parsed by the  SAX parser to validate against document DTD supplied with the document. It has thrown an exception while parsing the document. It means that the document is invalid because it has wrong structure.

The line number and column number indicate where the invalid structure had started.

You can try to replace wrong configuration file and make sure only one configuration file with the same name exists per project.

You should keep this file along source file for making modifications. When you package the project the file should copy to the `WEB-INF/classes` in the war archive. Make sure the file is the same as on the source folder.

Make clean before the build to remove files used by the previous build.